# Tensorflow Prediction Meanings

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, output

I've been working on a `DNNClassifier` model in Tensorflow, and I have gotten the model to train, evaluate and output results.

Here is the code I'm using to output my predictions:

```
predictions = classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn)

i = 0

for j, p in enumerate(predictions):
    print("Prediction %s: %s" % (j + 1, p["probabilities"]))
    i = i + 1
    if i > 100:
        break
```

`i` is being used to limit the results for testing purposes, because there's roughly 16,000 results being output and I don't need to see all of them for the purposes of what I'm trying to do right now.

The output I'm getting looks like this:

```
Prediction 1: [  5.11678644e-02   9.48832154e-01   3.84762299e-37]
Prediction 2: [ 0.0352843   0.96471566  0.        ]
Prediction 3: [  1.04001068e-04   9.99895930e-01   0.00000000e+00]
Prediction 4: [ 0.0323724   0.96762753  0.        ]
```

I know that these are probabilities of some kind, but I can't find documentation on what each one means. There's three per row, but only two categories, so I am guessing that one of them is a measure of certainty?

I realize that this is not strictly a programming question, rather it is more about output and documentation. However, before asking, I did look on other StackExchange sites and the TensorFlow documentation itself to try and find a better place to ask/an answer. The AI Stack Exchange website is still in beta and appears to have very little TensorFlow related activity (which is understandable, since many TensorFlow questions are programming questions), and I have had reasonable success on StackOverflow before when it comes to TF questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are classifying between three categories (labels). So what you are seeing in the predictions is your networks weighted guess for each possible category (label). For instance, in your first prediction the network results can be interpreted as: there is ~5% chance of the data belonging to the first category (label), a ~95% chance of the data belonging to the second category (label), and ~0% chance of the data belonging to the third category (label).

Comment: Hmmm. I thought I was only classifying between two labels. This `y=np.array(np.array(my_data[:, 11], dtype=int))` is how I set my labels array, and the data it's pulling from is all 1s and 0s.

Comment: Interesting. This is probably why the third label is always ~0 in the predictions. Did you set the number of classes to three when creating the object instance of the DNNClassifier?

Comment: Oops yes I did. That was one of the first things I added before I really understood what I was doing, I probably copied it straight from the MNIST tutorial -_-